# Jquery email validation user@admin.state.in.us

Tags: php, jquery

i need to validate email like user@admin.state.in.us, its invalid

after @ symbol allow only (2 dots) xxx@xx.sk.au, not allow more then that.

any one can help

My code is:

```
$.validator.addMethod( 
        'email',
        function(value, element){
            return this.optional(element) || /^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i.test(value);
        },
        "Verify you have a valid email address."
    );
```

Comment: Don't bother with this kind of validation; if it has an "@" and a TLD, it looks good enough.

Comment: My clients want this kind of validation, can help anyone

Comment: The validation takes place when you send an email; anything else is just a waste of time.

Comment: Yes your right, they want allow xxx@gmail.com.au  (not more then 2 dots)

Comment: If the email address works, why would they want to reject it? Sounds like needless micromanagement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regexp:

```
var emailReg = new RegExp(/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i);
if(emailReg.test(email)){
 // valid
}else{
 // in valid
}
```

Comment: Its not works for this xxx@xx.sk.au

Comment: It is working for me check it what u are doing wrong

Comment: if we type xxx@xxxx.sk.au.uk we need to show invalid, only allow after @ 2 dots